# OpenLDAP ppolicy load error

Tags: debian, openldap

I'm going to try run of openldap.
I created master-slave server and everything is ok.
However when I load the ppolicy module I get an error like below

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=module{0},cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
additional info: <olcModuleLoad> handler exited with 1
```

ldif file

```
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: ppolicy.la
```

I have previously uploaded a schematic of the ppolicy

```
 dn: cn=ppolicy,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: ppolicy
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.1 NAME 'pwdAttribute' EQUALITY
  objectIdentifierMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.38 )
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.2 NAME 'pwdMinAge' EQUALITY in
 tegerMatch ORDERING integerOrderingMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27
  SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {2}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.3 NAME 'pwdMaxAge' EQUALITY in
 tegerMatch ORDERING integerOrderingMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27
  SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {3}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.4 NAME 'pwdInHistory' EQUALITY
  integerMatch ORDERING integerOrderingMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1
 .27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {4}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.5 NAME 'pwdCheckQuality' EQUAL
 ITY integerMatch ORDERING integerOrderingMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.12
 1.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {5}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.6 NAME 'pwdMinLength' EQUALITY
  integerMatch ORDERING integerOrderingMatch  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.
 1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {6}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.7 NAME 'pwdExpireWarning' EQUA
 LITY integerMatch ORDERING integerOrderingMatch  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.
 121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {7}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.8 NAME 'pwdGraceAuthNLimit' EQ
 UALITY integerMatch ORDERING integerOrderingMatch  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.11
 5.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {8}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.9 NAME 'pwdLockout' EQUALITY b
 ooleanMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.7 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {9}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.10 NAME 'pwdLockoutDuration' E
 QUALITY integerMatch ORDERING integerOrderingMatch  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.1
 15.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {10}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.11 NAME 'pwdMaxFailure' EQUAL
 ITY integerMatch ORDERING integerOrderingMatch  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.1
 21.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {11}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.12 NAME 'pwdFailureCountInter
 val' EQUALITY integerMatch ORDERING integerOrderingMatch  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.
 1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {12}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.13 NAME 'pwdMustChange' EQUAL
 ITY booleanMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.7 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {13}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.14 NAME 'pwdAllowUserChange' 
 EQUALITY booleanMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.7 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {14}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.15 NAME 'pwdSafeModify' EQUAL
 ITY booleanMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.7 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {15}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4754.1.99.1 NAME 'pwdCheckModule' DESC 'L
 oadable module that instantiates "check_password() function' EQUALITY caseExa
 ctIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {16}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.1.30 NAME 'pwdMaxRecordedFailur
 e' EQUALITY integerMatch ORDERING integerOrderingMatch  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.
 1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcObjectClasses: {0}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4754.2.99.1 NAME 'pwdPolicyChecker' SUP top
  AUXILIARY MAY pwdCheckModule )
olcObjectClasses: {1}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.2.1 NAME 'pwdPolicy' SUP top AUXI
 LIARY MUST pwdAttribute MAY ( pwdMinAge $ pwdMaxAge $ pwdInHistory $ pwdCheck
 Quality $ pwdMinLength $ pwdExpireWarning $ pwdGraceAuthNLimit $ pwdLockout $
  pwdLockoutDuration $ pwdMaxFailure $ pwdFailureCountInterval $ pwdMustChange
  $ pwdAllowUserChange $ pwdSafeModify $ pwdMaxRecordedFailure ) )
```

Other modules are added without any problem.

```
slapcat -n 0 | grep -i module

dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module{0}
olcModulePath: /usr/libexec/openldap
olcModuleLoad: {0}back_mdb.la
olcModuleLoad: {1}syncprov.la
olcModuleLoad: {2}memberof.la
olcModuleLoad: {3}refint.la
structuralObjectClass: olcModuleList
olcAttributeTypes: {15}( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4754.1.99.1 NAME 'pwdCheckModule' DESC 'L
 oadable module that instantiates "check_password() function' EQUALITY caseExa
  AUXILIARY MAY pwdCheckModule )
```

What could be the problem? And how to fix it ?

I'm using these tutorials

https://kifarunix.com/install-and-setup-openldap-server-on-debian-11/
https://kifarunix.com/implement-openldap-password-policies/

Answer (score 0):

You should not add ppolicy schema. Add only ppolicy module and (optional, but recommended) ppolicy overlay.

policy schema is auto added with ppolicy module

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
slapd: 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

When slapd version is 2.4.x manually add ppolicy schema is necessary.